# Position Absolute Side by Side CSS

Tags: html, css

I am facing issue regarding placing balloons like this image:

[image]

```
    <div class="red_frame">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png"  class="r_over"/>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png"  class="r_over"/>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png"  class="r_over"/>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png"  class="r_over"/>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png"  class="r_over"/>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png"  class="r_over"/>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png"  class="r_over"/>
    </div>
.red_frame {
float: left;
width: 143px;
height: 346px;
margin: 0 2px 0 0;
position: relative;
}

.r_over
{position: relative;
right: 29px;}
```

Fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/fddkdvn4/

Comment: You can achieve this effect using negative margins: `.r_over { margin-left:-10px; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost near to solve it by yourself.

Playing with position is a good approach, but for this solution, you just simply need `margin-left: -10px`.

```css
.red_frame {
  float: left;
  width: 143px;
  height: 346px;
  margin: 0 2px 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
.r_over {
  position: relative;
  right: 29px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red_frame">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png" class="r_over" />
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png" class="r_over" />
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png" class="r_over" />
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png" class="r_over" />
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png" class="r_over" />
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png" class="r_over" />
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png" class="r_over" />
</div>
```

Comment: No worries, and good luck! Additionally, you can add `.r_over:first-child { margin-left: 0 };`. It will help not to style the first image.

Answer (score 1):

use

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4nsL1gxn/)

**CSS**

```
.red_frame {
float: left;
width: 143px;
height: 346px;
margin: 0 2px 0 0;
position: absolute;
}

.r_over
{margin-left:-10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin-left: -10px;` in `.r_over{}` but delete `postion:relative;` and `right:29px;`

Answer (score 1):

Negative margin would be the simplest way to do this. But, make sure you use the `:not(:first-child)` selector, otherwise the first image will also get the negative margin.

***Snippet:***

```css
.red_frame {
    width: 143px; height: 346px; margin: 8px;
}
.r_over:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red_frame">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png" class="r_over" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png" class="r_over" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png" class="r_over" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png" class="r_over" />
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/54SMF.png" class="r_over" />
</div>
```